# How to better optimize this mySQL query with subqueries

Tags: mysql, subquery, query-optimization

I am having some issues optimizing a mySQL query that I have been using sub-queries on to try and get the previous and next IDs based off the ID in the query. When I use the `EXPLAIN` function in mySQL it shows that one of my sub-queries is running through 690k+ rows, which is what I am guessing is affecting the performance.

I have tried to limit the sub-queries to return just just one result and used a `MIN` and `MAX` in the sub-queries, but both of those options still returned large sets of rows.

`SELECT c.*,
(SELECT id FROM cards WHERE id > '733290' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1) AS 'prev',
(SELECT id FROM cards WHERE id < '733290' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS 'next'
FROM cards c
LEFT JOIN albums a ON (a.id = cs.album_id)
WHERE c.id = '733290'`

In the explain this was the results:

```
id
select_type
table
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
Extra

5
SUBQUERY
cards
range
PRIMARY,user_id
PRIMARY
4
NULL
696177
Using where

4
SUBQUERY
cards
range
PRIMARY,user_id
PRIMARY
4
NULL
4
Using where
```

Edit: Here are the definitions for the cards table:

```
Keyname    Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  id  696183  A   No  
user_id BTREE   No  No  user_id 5438    A   No  
album   BTREE   No  No  album   258 A   No
```

Comment: May we see the table definition for the `cards` table?  We need to see this in order to be able to suggest some potential optimizations.

Comment: Updated the original post with this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a try:

```
SELECT c.*, cp.id AS `prev`, cn.id AS `next`
FROM cards c
LEFT JOIN cards cp ON c.id < cp.id
LEFT JOIN cards cpp ON c.id < cpp.id AND cp.id > cpp.id
LEFT JOIN cards cn ON c.id > cn.id
LEFT JOIN cards cnn ON c.id > cnn.id AND cn.id < cnn.id
WHERE c.id = 733290
 AND cpp.id IS NULL
 AND cnn.id IS NULL
```

Explanation: Join `c` to `cp`, which has a greater id, but also make sure the set of rows `cpp` with an id *between* `c.id` and `cp.id` is an empty set. That is, the outer join must return NULL.

Do the same for `cn`.

Comment: This assumes that `id` is a monotonically increasing column.

Comment: Yes it does. Do you think that would be unusual?

Comment: I guess I was thinking defensively that this was a general lead/lag problem, where that might not be the case.  +1 to answer, which might work here.

Comment: I am getting `null` returns for next and prev using this query. Oh, and yes, the prev/next are reversed because the data is shown in DESC order.

Comment: I realized my first try was obviously wrong. It could never return the prev and next rows because of the WHERE clause condition. I've replaced it with a different answer.

Comment: @BillKarwin - Are you trying to see if there is only one row in each direction?  But that would happen only if there were exactly 3 rows in the table, and the query were for the middle row.

Comment: I'm trying to make sure `cp` and `cn` are the immediate next and previous rows, i.e. no other rows exist that are closer to the primary row.

Answer (score 0):

`EXPLAIN` provides bogus information, especially when `LIMIT` is involved.

Your query is optimal and will not really touch more than 1 row in each direction.

(And I have not figured out what Bill is trying to achieve!)

To get a more reliable count of number of rows touched, do this:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler_read%';
```

For a similar query (on a table with 3.1M rows), I got

```
+-----------------------+-------+
| Variable_name         | Value |
+-----------------------+-------+
| Handler_read_first    | 0     |
| Handler_read_key      | 3     |
| Handler_read_last     | 0     |
| Handler_read_next     | 0     |
| Handler_read_prev     | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd      | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd_next | 0     |
+-----------------------+-------+
```

Add up the numbers (and get 3); that will be exactly(?) how many rows were touched.  3 seems correct for your query.